# How to cache tab using jquery function for dynamic index number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

```
$('#operation_detail_main_tab').tabs({cache:true,show: function( event, ui ){
    if(ui.index!=6){
        $('#operation_detail_main_tab').tabs('load', ui.index);
    }
}});
```

I want the `ui.index!=6` part, to have dynamic value. It should receive a value from somewhere.

How to do it as the value is from JSP. I know parameter in jsp is specified like `${my variable}`,  but is it possible to pass it to javascript function?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value onto the page then you can reference it. When the page is rendering, create a `script` block and print out the variable. Assuming you have a variable called `myVariable` in JSP that you want to use:

```
<script>
    var myVariable = <c:out value="${myVariable}" />;
</script>
```

Do this in the head of the document and then you can change

```
if(ui.index!=6){
```

Into

```
if(ui.index!=myVariable){
```

An alternative would be to AJAX in the number, storing it in a non-global position.

Comment: Can you suggest a better than the above answer i provided?

Comment: @user3053885 I've updated my example to include the printing of the JSP variable. You would just need to work out what that variable would be either with some `if/else`s or with a `case` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <c:if test="${flag5!=null}"> 
    <script>
  $('#operation_detail_main_tab').tabs({cache:true,show: function( event, ui ){
     if(ui.index!=4){
          $('#operation_detail_main_tab').tabs('load', ui.index);
  }
 }});

   </script>
   </c:if>

   <c:if test="${flag8!=null}"> 
    <script>
     $('#operation_detail_main_tab').tabs 
                 ({cache:true,show:function(event, ui ){
        if(ui.index!=6){
               $('#operation_detail_main_tab').tabs('load', ui.index);
     }
     }});

  </script>
  </c:if>
```

Comment: I actually ended up doing the above code, but it solved my problem.
But i wonder is there any more elegant way?